# Which rule should one use on these two inverse Laplace transforms?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have an ode $y''-6y'+9y=t^2e^{3t}$, which I solved using the Laplace transform. However, when I come to the end result, which I need to do an inverse transform on, I get something which does not appear to be readily compatible with inverse laplace transform tables.

With I.C. $y(0)=2$, $y'(0)=6$:

$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{y''\}=s^2Y-y'(0)-y(0)=s^2Y-8$

$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{y'\}=sY-y(0)=sY-2$

$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{y\}=Y$

This gives:

$s^2Y-6sY+9Y=t^2e^{3t}-4$

Then I get:

\begin{equation}
Y=\frac{t^2e^{3t}}{s^2-6s+9}-4\frac{1}{s^2-6s+9}
\end{equation}

which gives the following inverse:

\begin{equation}
y(t)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{t^2e^{3t}}{(s-3)^2}\}-4\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}\}
\end{equation}

Using wolfram, this gives $y(t)=e^{6t}t^3-4te^{3t}$, but there are some familiarities here that suggest that a specific rule should be applied? If there is, which rule would that be?

Thanks

Comment: $y(0)=2, y'(0)=6$

Comment: Yes, I did that already. I add it to the question.

Comment: You only Laplace transformed ONE SIDE of the equation. Do both sides. $Y$ should not have $t$ in it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$y''-6y'+9y=t^2e^{3t}, y(0) = 2, y'(0) = 6$$

Taking the Laplace Transform

$$(s^2 Y(s) -s y(0) - y'(0)) - 6(s Y(s) -y(0)) + 9 Y(s) = \dfrac{2}{(s-3)^3}$$

Adding the initial conditions

$$(s^2 Y(s) -2s -6) - 6(s Y(s) -2) + 9 Y(s) = \dfrac{2}{(s-3)^3}$$

Grouping terms

$$(s^2 -6s + 9)Y(s) - 2s + 6 = \dfrac{2}{(s-3)^3}$$

Simplifying

$$(s-3)^2 Y(s) = \dfrac{2}{(s-3)^3} + 2 s - 6$$

Solving for $Y(s)$

$$Y(s) = \dfrac{2}{(s-3)^5} + \dfrac{2s}{(s-3)^2} - \dfrac{6}{(s-3)^2}$$

Finding the inverse Laplace transform

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{12} e^{3 t} t^4+2 e^{3 t}$$

Comment: Thanks Moo, I see the error! I forgot that s in front of the transform of the first derivative!

Comment: Thanks, that is noted!

Comment: PS: So which rule did you use to get those transforms?

Comment: I used item 23, for the first and second from https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx. For the middle term, I wrote the partial fraction decomposition $\dfrac{6}{(s-3)^2}+\dfrac{2}{s-3}$ and then used item 23 and item 2. Clear?

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!